# Json_encode is not working for null value

Tags: php, oracle11g, symfony-2.8

what i need

- i need to convert array to json.

array o/p

```
 Array
( 
[ID] => 70
[MM_USER_PROFILE_ID] => 1
[FOS_USER_ID] => 84
[TYPE] => ALERT
[FILE_ID] => 157
[PRIORITY] => Medium
[TITLE] => test csv
[DESCRIPTION] => Resource id #390
[IS_ACTIVE] => Y
[CREATED_AT] => 2017-03-15 11:24:28
[UPDATED_AT] => 
[CREATED_BY] => 84
[UPDATED_BY] => 
[LEVEL_ID] => 
[USER_ID] => 84
[LOG_ID] => 
)
```

php code

```
   $temp = array();

    $selectQ = "SELECT COUNT(*) as  new_if_count  ";
    $total_count = $this->container->get('db_core_function_services')->runRawSql($selectQ);


    foreach($notification_result as $key =>$value)
    {
      //solution 1 i tried json_encode
        $temp['all_notifications']=json_encode($value);
    }


  print_r($tmp)  o/p false.

  //solution 2 i tried
    $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    $response = new Response($serializer->serialize($temp, 'json'));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
```

- please suggest the solution how can i encode this array.

error

```
 An unexpected value could not be normalized: NULL
```

- as  i have googled i have issue was in parsing null value from array.
- please suggest

solution i found ['description'] was blob content that was creating problem.

code that works for me

```
   foreach($notification_result as $key =>$value)
    {
        if(array_key_exists('DESCRIPTION', $value)){
            $blob =  $value['DESCRIPTION'];
            $value['DESCRIPTION'] = stream_get_contents($blob);
        }
        $temp['all_notifications']=$value;
    }
    $temp_count=$total_count[0];

    $data=array_merge($temp_count,$temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($notification_result as $key =>$value) {
      //solution 1 i tried json_encode
//if (!empty($value)) //uncomment if need cut empty variables
        $array .= $temp['all_notifications'] = array($key =>$value);
    }    
$json = json_encode ($array);
    echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize first that is an array..Just try it by adding this line before the foreach loop

`$temp = array();`

Comment: Then first of all, store the fetching value as array..then convert it as JSON..try it `foreach($notification_result as $key =>$value)
    {
     
        $temp['all_notifications']=$value;
    }         $json_file = json_encode($temp);  `

Comment: i have written wrong in that line..correction  `$temp['all_notifications'] .= $value; `